# Salesforce Rest System.HttpResponse [Status=Not Found, StatusCode=404]

Tags: apex, rest-api, rest, apexrest, remote-site-settings

I need to invoke a REST class exposed in my own developer edition org.
 
Its a GET Method, and when I test the endpoint using Workbench, I get the expected result.

Now the problem is, I created a new `Remote Site Setting` and pasted the URL from my own org. In this case remote site setting which i saved is `https://ckdomaintest-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com` and invoking the same method with same parameters is not executing properly.

I am getting the following error:

> System.HttpResponse [Status=Not Found, StatusCode=404]

So I feel the remote site is not being recognized. How do I call my own org?

Comment: That's not what `Remote Site Settings` do. They allow you to make *outbound* calls to the given address. They do not affect *inbound* calls at all.

Comment: Thanks So much for the quick reply. But how can i invoke method which is exposed in my own org ? any lead be be really helpful.

Comment: I think you need Salesforce2Salesforce or you can expose the endpoint unauthenticated via Site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do that you need to call the

1. standard [REST API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_rest_resources.htm) to get you authenticated
2. Understand the different [authentication](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_understanding_authentication.htm)
3. Once you are done with authentication call your custom API with access token received from step 2.

You can get sample code from [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/82442/salesforce-to-salesforce-connection-using-apex-callouts-and-soap-apis) and [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000099zbIAA) and from the links provided

generally, we don't call rest API in the same org most of the time we call rest api of another salesforce org. if you are already inside of the salesforce org and want to invoke the custom rest api you need to set the header.

```
req.setHeader('Authorization', 'OAuth '+UserInfo.getSessionId());
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: If you use `1.` instead of `1)`, you get an ordered list.